# Displaying iPhone screen on mac without airserver

Tags: mac, iphone, ios

Is there any way to display an iPhone screen on a Mac without using airserver?

Airserver and similar wifi-based products make the transfer very slow. I was hoping for a similar solution using the iPhone's charging cable, something like what iTunes sync does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! If you have an iPhone runnining, iOS 8 an Apple Mac running Mac OSX 10.10.x (Yosemite) you will need your iPhone USB cable to connect to your Mac. Then launch QuickTime Player. You may be asked to "Trust" your iOS device, say yes. Then in the menu bar for QuickTime, go to File-->New Movie Recording...

In the new movie window, you will see the record button. There is a drop down menu to the right of the record button. Select the iPhone or iOS device as the video source!

Neato!